# Using deprecated functions on older API versions?

Tags: android, filesystems, storage, android-file, android-api-levels

Background: I am making my app with minimum API level 17.

I was looking up ways to get the size of the file system and saw this:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StatFs.html

However, a lot of the newer functions are only available in API level 18 upward, and the older versions are now deprecated.

How might I correctly use something like http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html to say, "If the user's API level is 17, use the deprecated version of these functions, but if API level is 18+, use the newer versions of these functions"? Would I need to use the deprecation annotation somehow?

Comment: Google a bit. You'll see that it's recommended by Google, with examples and more. There's even an annotation to suppress the deprecation for lint.

Comment: I did Google but didn't see anything. What should I be Googling for?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use the deprecated method if the OS version is below 18 or use the newer method if the OS version is above or equals to 18.

For example:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private long getAvailableBlocks(StatFs statFs) {
    long availableBlocks;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
        availableBlocks = statFs.getAvailableBlocksLong();
    } else {
        availableBlocks = statFs.getAvailableBlocks();
    }

    return availableBlocks;
}
```